# Something like PHP's __call() in Actionscript

Tags: php, actionscript-3

Suppose (as an example) that I have a class which I want to log all method calls to.

In PHP this can be accomplished quickly and easily with `__call()`, or in Python with decorators.

What would be the easiest way to accomplish the same thing in Actionscript 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend [`flash.utils.Proxy`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/Proxy.html) and use the `flash.utils.flash_proxy` namespace. There's methods similar to `__get`, `__set` and methods for delete methods as well. For example, the `__call` method is:

```
override flash_proxy function callProperty(name:*, ...rest):*;
```

so if have a class that extends Proxy, you do:

```
var test:MyObject = new MyObject();
test.myMethodThatIsntDefined("param");
```

then callProperty will be called and name will be set to "myMethodThatIsntDefined" and "param" will be in the ...rest array.

The link to the asdoc has a simple implementation that should get you going. I typically use the Proxy class for something like an API. For example, back in the day I had a Flickr API wrapper that translated the name of the function call to an API method name in the Flickr API. Something like:

```
flickr.galleriesGetPhotos();
```

and in the callProperty I'd split on the first word to get the API name "flickr.galleries.get_photos". The names were different back then I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the Proxy class.

```
 dynamic class MyProxy extends Proxy {
 flash_proxy override function callProperty(name:*, ...rest):* {
   try {
     // custom code here
   }
   catch (e:Error) {
     // respond to error here
   }
```

}

Refer:http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/Proxy.html